# Error prebuild react-native, build.gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, native

When you first start the application, this error appears. I don't understand what it can be connected with.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\xxxx\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
   > Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the order of execution. I think your computer environment is `Windows`.

1. You recommend installing `Node` and `Python2` via [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), a
   popular package manager for `Windows`.
2. `choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8`

If you have already installed `Node` on your system, make sure it is `Node 8.3` or newer. If you already have a JDK on your system, make sure it is `version 8` or newer.

3. Download and install Android Studio. Choose a "Custom" setup when
   prompted to select an installation type. Make sure the boxes next to
   all of the following are checked:

   - `Android SDK`
   - `Android SDK Platform`
   - `Performance (Intel ® HAXM) (See here for AMD)`
   - `Android Virtual Device`

Then, click "Next" to install all of these components.

4. `Android Studio` installs the latest `Android SDK` by default.
   Building a React Native app with native code, however, requires the
   `Android 9 (Pie) SDK` in particular. Additional Android SDKs can be
   installed through the SDK Manager in `Android Studio.`

The SDK is installed, by default, at the following location:

```
c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

5. Add platform-tools to Path
   Open the System pane under `System and Security` in the Windows Control Panel, then click on Change settings.... Open the Advanced tab and click on `Environment Variables`.... Select the Path variable, then click Edit. Click New and add the path to platform-tools to the list.

The default location for this folder is:

```
c:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

6. `React Native` has a built-in command line interface, which you can
   use to generate a new project. You can access it without installing
   anything globally using `npx`, which ships with Node.js.

   npx react-native init AwesomeProject
7. Run `npx react-native run-android` inside your `React Native` project
   folder:

   cd AwesomeProject
   npx react-native run-android

If everything is set up correctly, you should see your new app running in your Android emulator shortly.

Comment: @Anton  If my answer was helpful, would you please select the 'V' sign and arrow for my answer?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your React-native Project -> Android
2. Create a file `local.properties`
3. Open the file
4. paste your Android SDK path like below

in Windows sdk.dir = `C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\sdk`

in macOS `sdk.dir = /Users/USERNAME/Library/Android/sdk`

in linux `sdk.dir = /home/USERNAME/Android/Sdk`
Replace `USERNAME` with your user name

Now, Run the react-native run-android in your terminal.